# Styled-components with components in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components, next.js

I am setting up a simple Nextjs boilerplate but can't seem to get the styled-components to work. In my file Header.tsx:

```
// Core Module Imports
import Link from "next/link";
import * as React from "react";

// Styled-Component Imports
import styled from "../theme/theme";

class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Link href="/about">
                   <a>About Us</a>
                </Link>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const StyledHeader = styled(Header)`
    width: 100vw;
    height: 10vh;
    background: #2a2c39;
    color: #ff0000;
    link-style: none;
`;

export default StyledHeader;
```

As you can see, I set up a simple Header component and then below I used styled() to define my css. In my file Index.tsx:

```
// Core Module Imports
import * as React from "react";

import StyledHeader from "../components/Header";

class Index extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <StyledHeader />
                <p>Test Change</p>
                <div>Example Div</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Index;
```

Obviously I am doing something wrong because it is not working and all I get it an unstyled link. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone that sees this and has a similar issue, check out this: 
https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/1942#issuecomment-313925454

Fixed my issue.

> Hey guys. At version 3.0.1-beta.13+, you could set passHref to Link (as a boolean property) to expose its href to styled-components (or any other library that wraps its  tag).

```
const StyledLink = styled.a`
  color: red;
  background: blue;
`

export default ({ href, name }) => (
  <Link prefetch href={href} passHref>
    <StyledLink>{name}</StyledLink>
  </Link>
)
```

There are solutions in the GitHub issue for people using `next-routes`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `this.props.className` into the root element of `Header` so the styled wrapper can pass a generated class name in:

```
class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={this.props.className}>
                <Link href="/about">
                   <a>About Us</a>
                </Link>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do that I get a [ts] error that reads:                                   
'Property 'className' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<{}>'.'

Comment: I'm not sure what that error is. I don't have much Typescript experience. You could also try `<div {...this.props}>`

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with how typescript handles prop types. You might have to declare `className` as a prop of `Header`. I'm not sure what the right way to do this is.

Comment: Hmm. Ok, I will try and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Found an answer and posted it above. Thanks for your contributions!

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:**

Create a `_document.js` file in your `/pages` folder and paste this in. It should work immediately

```
import Document from 'next/document'
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components'

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet()
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage

    try {
      ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
          enhanceApp: (App) => (props) =>
            sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
        })

      const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
      return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: (
          <>
            {initialProps.styles}
            {sheet.getStyleElement()}
          </>
        ),
      }
    } finally {
      sheet.seal()
    }
  }
}
```

**If you want styled-components to work automatically on every page/component**, you "can create a ServerStyleSheet and add a provider to your React tree, that accepts styles via a context API." In Nextjs, you would do so by adding it to your `_document.js` file...

You can read about it more if you follow these links:

1. [Styled-Components: SSR Documentation](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#server-side-rendering)
2. [Nextjs: Customer Render
   Page](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document#customizing-renderpage)

Thankfully there's already a working example you can use from the styled-components people themselves!

Check it out here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-styled-components/pages/_document.js

Comment: Here's for TS -> https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document#typescript

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you're searching for but **styling a Next Link** is pretty easy

```
import Link from 'next/link'

const StyledLink = styled(Link)`
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
`
```

and then use it like

```
<StyledLink href={route.path}>
    {route.name}
</StyledLink>
```